# Charge number and phase as canonical variables

Tags: quantum-mechanics, commutator, canonical-conjugation

In the derivation of the Hamiltonian of a Cooper Pair Box, it is stated that the junction phase difference variable $\delta$ and the charge number variable $N$ satisfy the canonical commutation relation $[\delta, N] = i$. I don't understand why this is the case, and was wondering if there was a physical explanation for this.

Answer (score 3):

The result is only an approximation. For an entertaining account  this   subject (one with a long history) see [here](https://astro.swarthmore.edu/comps/phase.pdf) (revised link). The basic point is that the number operator only has non-negative eigenvalues, but the commutator of the phase angle $\theta$ (your $\delta$) and $N$ being
$$
[\theta, N]= i
$$
implies  that
$$
e^{i\theta}Ne^{-i\theta}= N+i[\theta,N]\\
= N-1. 
$$
Thus $N$ and $N-1$ are unitarily equivalent.  This can only be so if the eigenvalues of $N$ and $N-1$ coincide and that  is impossible if $N$ only has non-negative eigenvalues.

If one only  needs  large values of $N$ the errors in assuming $[\theta,N]=i$ are not important, so this is a popular approxiation in superconducting devices.

Comment: Hello, @mikestone. Do you have any other reference about this (as I have no access to the CERN link that you've posted)? I'm working to understand a related issue regarding a transformation $\hat{c}^\dagger=e^{i\hat{\theta}}$ ([here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/605411/rotor-representation-of-creation-and-annihilation-operators#comment1778677_605411) there is more context). I can't find this anywhere.

Comment: The CERN link seems to have changed to rquire a password..  I will look for another sources and add them..

Comment: @Mr. Feynman A recent freely available paper with references is https://arxiv.org/pdf/2205.09481.pdf .

Comment: Thank you for the reference.